# Can't assign a value because `value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `histPrice` with a column called `Allocation %` and a sub-index column called 'test', which I set it to 5.

```
[Input]: histPrice['Allocation %', "test"] = 5

[Output]: print(histPrice['Allocation %'])

Date           test  
2019-11-04     5
2019-11-01     5
2019-10-31     5
2019-10-30     5
2019-10-29     5
2019-10-28     5
...
```

I want to replace the value of the first index, `2019-11-04`, with a value 10. I tried the following logic:

```
histPrice['Allocation %'].loc[histPrice['Allocation %'].index[0],'test'] = 10
```

After running the code, I see nothing has been updated where I still see 5 in the first row, instead of 10 with the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I'm assuming this is happening because the original copy is not being overwritten. How can I re-write the logic so the value gets replaced properly?